# amcharts использование данных json из контроллера

Tags: javascript, java, json

Добрый вечер.
Пытаюсь прикрутить график amcharts на страницу.
У меня есть java контроллер, который выдает данные в json формате:

```
[
  {"created":"Mar 13, 2016 8:11:47 PM","budget":200.0},
  {"created":"Mar 13, 2015 8:12:08 PM","budget":123.0},
  {"created":"Mar 1, 2017 2:53:27 PM","updated":"Mar 5, 2017 12:05:03 AM","budget":10.0},
  {"created":"Mar 13, 2015 8:12:26 PM","budget":123333.0}
]
```

по адресу `/dealDataJson`.

Использую скрипт amchart для построения графика:

```js
<!-- Chart code -->
  <script>

    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "type": "serial",
      "theme": "light",
      "marginTop":0,
      "marginRight": 80,
      "categoryField": "Date",
      "dataLoader":{ "url": "/dealDataJson",
            },
      "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
      }],
      "graphs": [{
        "id":"g1",
        "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletSize": 8,
        "lineColor": "#d1655d",
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
        "type": "smoothedLine",
        "valueField": "budget"
      }],
      "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph":"g1",
        "gridAlpha":0,
        "color":"#888888",
        "scrollbarHeight":55,
        "backgroundAlpha":0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha":0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor":"#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha":0,
        "autoGridCount":true,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha":0,
        "graphLineAlpha":0.2,
        "graphLineColor":"#c2c2c2",
        "selectedGraphLineColor":"#888888",
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha":1

      },
      "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY",
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineEnabled":true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,
        "valueLineAlpha":0.5,
        "fullWidth":true
      },
      "dataDateFormat": "M d, yyyy kk.mm.ss a",
      "categoryField": "created",
      "categoryAxis": {
        "minPeriod": "MM",
        "parseDates": true,
        "minorGridAlpha": 0.1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true
      },
      "export": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    });

    chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
    if(chart.zoomChart){
      chart.zoomChart();
    }


  </script>
```

в котором указываю `"dataLoader":{ "url": "/dealDataJson"}`, но он не хочет обращаться по url.

Что-то я делаю неправильно или что-то упускаю, но что?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: "Не хочет" выражается в какой-то ошибке или даже в Network запрос не наблюдается?

Comment: ошибок никаких не наблюдается. Страница отображается но как бы с пустым графиком. Отслеживаю обращение к контроллеру с url: /DeliaSoftTest и там тишина.

Comment: если вместо "dataLoader":{ "url": "/dealDataJson"} ставлю "dataProvider": [{
        "created": "1950",
        "value": -0.307
    }, {
        "created": "1951",
        "value": -0.168
    }, {
        "created": "1952",
        "value": -0.073
    }], то график отображается с данными

Comment: Могу предположить, что для `/dealDataJson` не задан заголовок `content-type`. Попробуйте указать его, а также `"format": "json"` в вашем `dataLoader`

Comment: для /dealDataJson не задан заголовок content-type    - подскажите пожалуйста более детально, куда и как его задать?

Comment: Перед выводом `json` в вашем `/dealDataJson`  добавить `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. Вы уверены, что обращение к `/dealDataJson` происходит?

Comment: добавил хедер в анотацию     @RequestMapping(value = "/dealDataJson", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
Обращение к /dealDataJson не происходит

Comment: У вас есть публичный url, на котором можно посмотреть, что вообще происходит?

Comment: неа, все развернуто на локальной машине. Дополнительную информацию могу выложить сюда

Comment: Плагин dataLoader вы же подключили?

Comment: <script src="amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  прописан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
```

проблема была в ссылках на скрипты, вот рабочие